# Repeating inbox entries on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

Inbox items in the right menu are repeating on Stack Exchange Android app beta.

[image: Here is screnshot]

**Note:**

Comment: Can confirm that this happens sometimes. Cannot pinpoint when.

Comment: I cannot pinpoint when and how it happens. This is the first time I have noticed.